# Formula to decide if cell is visible

Tags: excel

Can I use a formula to determine if a cell is not in a hidden row/column?

I know that there are related formulas like subtotal and aggregate, but I don't quite understand those. And subtotal only seems to care about filtered row, not about hidden rows in general.

I'm looking for something like:

```
=ISVISIBLE(A1)
```

Is it possible combine formulas that arrive at that functionality?

Comment: Visible as currently on screen? Or not in a hidden column / row?

Comment: Visible as not in a hidden row / column. I clarified the question

Comment: it is easy to search for this on the Internet... but anyway Pingu's answer is excellent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no built-in formula for this. However, you can use VBA / write your own function to achieve this.

```
Function isvisible(cellname As String)
    isvisible = Not (Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(cellname).EntireColumn.Hidden Or Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(cellname).EntireRow.Hidden)
End Function
```

Then you can type `=isvisible("A1")` in a cell to get the result.

If you don't like the double quotes, here is another way:

```
Function isvisible(rng As Range)
    isvisible = Not (rng.EntireColumn.Hidden Or rng.EntireRow.Hidden)
End Function
```

Then you can type `=isvisible(A1)` in a cell to get the result.

Comment: I would like to use a macro disabled workbook, so I would really like if there was an non-vba solution

Answer (score 6):

If by subtotal() you refer to this option:

```
= IF( SUBTOTAL(103,A2)=1, "VISIBLE", "HIDDEN (or blank)" )
```

From this [post](https://superuser.com/questions/885159/excel-function-determine-if-a-cell-is-visible)... then that's your answer. Not being able to use it outside of a table mostly means that your data should be stored in a table, not that there's a critical limitation of that formula.

I would say - create tables for your data instead. It's always worth it using tables, whether or not you use VBA. I am yet to encounter a workbook where it wouldn't be better to use tables instead of raw ranges. Even if it's a small document, it ends up being faster.

Answer (score 2):

Since I spent more time than I want to admit searching far and wide for a non-VBA solution that would work for me (since a macro enabled workbook is not a viable option in this enterprise environment), I wanted to share the below answer I came across so that it can help speed the search for the next poor soul.

The below formula returns a 1 if the referenced cell column is visible, and 0 if it is not. Removing the `N()` portion of the formula returns a Boolean result (TRUE/FALSE) in lieu of Binary (1/0).

```
=N(CELL("width",A1)>0)
```

This is where I totally plagiarized this from:
[Count Visible Columns](https://exceljet.net/formula/count-visible-columns)

Comment: This is a very good answer! However, the `"width"` info_type returns a 2D array: **{#,BOOLEAN}**. # is a numerical width, BOOLEAN exposes whether the column's width has been untouched or resized by the user. So as a general solution, you should tweak the formula to: `=INDEX(CELL("width",A1),1)>0` (the `N(…)` function is beyond the scope of the question). **NOTE:** The `CELL(…)` function is volatile and may cause performance issues. Furthermore, is neither triggered by re-sizing nor un/hiding columns.