# Why does this ISVISIBLE() custom function return #VALUE! until I press return?

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, vba

This answer to [Formula to decide if cell is visible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28538263/2174781) suggests this function to say whether a cell is visible:

```
Function isvisible(rng As Range)
    isvisible = Not (rng.EntireColumn.Hidden Or rng.EntireRow.Hidden)
End Function
```

This function works great in conjunction with `INDIRECT()`. I have a cell reference in `A1` and I am using `isvisible(INDIRECT(A1))`.

However, when I hide the cell that `A1` is referring to (on another sheet), I get the `#VALUE!` until I enter the formula bar and hit return.

My questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. How can I prevent the `#VALUE!` errors from arising?

---

Edit:

The rows are hidden/unhidden by clicking on a series of checkboxes with macro code like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Rows("13:17").Hidden = Not Rows("13:17").Hidden
End Sub
```

Comment: I could not reproduce your error. When I hide the cell, I don't get #Value! - the function result simply does not change until the workbook is recalculated. There must be something in the way you use Indirect. What is the content of cell A1?

Comment: @RADO: The value is 'BA2 Optional'!F15 (referencing another sheet). The formula is concatenating the sheet name, F column and row number, which lives in cell C2: ="'BA2 Optional'!F"&C2

Comment: I still couldn't reproduce your error; most likely, because I am using a blank workbook while you have a more complex one. This link might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170983/vba-udf-returning-value

Comment: @RADO: I didn't create this workbook, so just stumbled across the VBA code for hiding/unhiding rows based on a checkbox. I've edited this into the question.

Comment: A-h, that's different. Now I have reproduced it. See the answer below,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your code like this:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Rows("13:17").Hidden = Not Rows("13:17").Hidden
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("MySheet").Calculate
End Sub
```

where MySheet is the name of the sheet with the isvisible function. If you have the formula in many sheets, recalculate the entire book:

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
    Rows("13:17").Hidden = Not Rows("13:17").Hidden
    Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I was going to post a duplicate answer, as we had the same thought at the same time :-)